# CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException when reading from SQLite database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm trying to get dara from SQLite database and my app crashes everytime I try to do it. Here's the logcat output:

```
12-30 07:17:15.194: E/AndroidRuntime(9412): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-30 07:17:15.194: E/AndroidRuntime(9412): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.testparsing/com.example.testparsing.Urnik}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 2
12-30 07:17:15.194: E/AndroidRuntime(9412):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
12-30 07:17:15.194: E/AndroidRuntime(9412):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
12-30 07:17:15.194: E/AndroidRuntime(9412):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
12-30 07:17:15.194: E/AndroidRuntime(9412):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
12-30 07:17:15.194: E/AndroidRuntime(9412):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-30 07:17:15.194: E/AndroidRuntime(9412):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-30 07:17:15.194: E/AndroidRuntime(9412):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
12-30 07:17:15.194: E/AndroidRuntime(9412):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-30 07:17:15.194: E/AndroidRuntime(9412):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
12-30 07:17:15.194: E/AndroidRuntime(9412):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
12-30 07:17:15.194: E/AndroidRuntime(9412):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
12-30 07:17:15.194: E/AndroidRuntime(9412):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-30 07:17:15.194: E/AndroidRuntime(9412): Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 2
12-30 07:17:15.194: E/AndroidRuntime(9412):     at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:424)
12-30 07:17:15.194: E/AndroidRuntime(9412):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
12-30 07:17:15.194: E/AndroidRuntime(9412):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:50)
12-30 07:17:15.194: E/AndroidRuntime(9412):     at com.example.testparsing.Urnik.onCreate(Urnik.java:20)
12-30 07:17:15.194: E/AndroidRuntime(9412):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
12-30 07:17:15.194: E/AndroidRuntime(9412):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
12-30 07:17:15.194: E/AndroidRuntime(9412):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
12-30 07:17:15.194: E/AndroidRuntime(9412):
```

Reading from cursor (app crashes at second line):

```
Cursor c = db.getSubject("Ponedeljek", 2, "4c");
String predmet = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(SQLiteHelper.PREDMET));
```

getSubject function:

```
Cursor getSubject(String dan, int ura, String oddelek){
    String[] columns = new String[]{SQLiteHelper.PREDMET};
    String selection = SQLiteHelper.DAN+"=? and "+SQLiteHelper.URA+"=? and "+SQLiteHelper.ODDELEK+"=?";
    String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{dan, Integer.toString(ura), oddelek};
    open();
    return db.query(
            SQLiteHelper.IME_TABELE, 
            columns, 
            selection, 
            selectionArgs,
            null, null, null);
}
```

Comment: https://www.google.pl/search?q=CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before accessing cursor column values, you'll have to move it to point to a valid row using e.g. `moveToFirst()` or `moveToNext()`. These methods will return `true` if the cursor points to a valid row after the call.

Comment: So basically you need to point the cursor to a certain row, or else it'll be pointing to a null (-1) row and it crashes. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Best practice to reading from Cursor:

```
if ( !cursor.moveToFirst() ) {
//no rows to read
}

do {
    String foo = cursor.getString(..); }
while( cursor.moveToNext() );
```

Comment: Before you edited the answer it would have skipped the first row. Now it will fail if there are no rows. Need to check the result of `moveToFirst()`